# How do I extract the Currency from "Total Currency" VBA /BDP

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I have a list:

```
           Price in EUR       Price in Home Country
Total AUD
Svenska     10
Ubinse      15 
Illuao      20
Total USD
Zelo        12
Jhasma      11
Hedsaw      17
```

Ideally, I want to use VBA to insert a a sub that inserts a BDP function in each row of the column `Price in Home Country`

So like:

```
for i = 1 to 7
if IsEmpty(Cells(i,2)) = True Then
Else
Cells(i,3).Value = PriceHomeCountry(Cells(i,2), Cells(ws.Rows.Count,2).End(xlBottom).Offset(1,-1)
End if 
Next i
```

Please note I want to use `Cells(ws.Rows.Count,2).End(xlBottom).Offset(1,-1).Value` to refer to the "Total `Insert Currency`" above

I am unsure how to structure the `PriceHomeCountry()` function

**Suggestion:**

```
Function PriceHomeCountry(rng1 as Range, rng2 as Range)
'I want to basically separate the "Total" from the "Currency" in rng2,let's call the result rng2.1
PriceHomeCountry = "=BDP( "EUR" & rng2.1 & " Crncy")*rng1
End Function
```

Comment: You don't need = True just if IsEmpty(Cells(i,2))

Comment: So next to _Svenska_ you want the formula `=BDP("EUR AUD Crncy")*10`?  Shouldn't there be a comma before `Crncy`?

Comment: I don't have the add-in so don't want to add as an answer - would this work:  `PriceHomeCountry = WorksheetFunction.BDP("EUR " & Split(rng2, " ")(1), "Crncy") * rng1`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it won't work - the op probably needs something like `Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=BDP(""EURAUD Curncy"", ""PX_LAST"") * 10`. But the op needs to clarify his question as you asked in your first comment.

Comment: @assylias I was wondering about that - and looking at your profile you'd have a better idea than me.  I was also thinking of BDP as a worksheet function, but it's in an add-in so is just a `Public Function` that could be called from VBA with something like (for example) `DEBUG.PRINT BDP("EURAUD Curncy", "PX_LAST")`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook No that won't work - it can only be used in a formula. To access it programmatically is a bit more involved.

Comment: @assylias  Damn.  At least my code gives the way to enter it as a formula.  Do you have a link to any resources so I could get my head around the "more involved" bit?

Comment: I don't think the reference document is publicly available - but the code would look like the last piece of code in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39669487/829571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code *should* do the trick.  I can't test using the BDP formula as I don't have the add-in so I've given three ways to use it.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim CalcRange As Range
    Dim CountryRange As Range
    Dim TotalCell As Range
    Dim HomeCountry As String

    'Every reference to a range that starts "." will be referencing Sheet1.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Define the ranges we're working with.
        Set CountryRange = .Range("A2:A9")
        Set CalcRange = .Range("C2:C9")

        'Look at each cell in C2:C9.
        For Each rCell In CalcRange
            If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Offset(, -1)) Then
                'Find the first cell before the current rCell in column A that contains the word Total.
                Set TotalCell = CountryRange.Find(What:="Total", After:=rCell.Offset(, -2), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

                'If found then check the found value is in a row higher than rCell.
                ' - FIND wraps when it reaches the top so could find a Total from lower down.
                If Not TotalCell Is Nothing Then
                    If TotalCell.Row < rCell.Row Then
                        rCell = PriceHomeCountry(rCell.Offset(, -1), TotalCell)

                        'If PriceHomeCountry isn't working this will place the formula in column C.
                        'rCell.Formula = "=BDP(""EUR" & Split(TotalCell, " ")(1) & " Curncy"",""PX_LAST"")"
                    End If                        
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub

Public Function PriceHomeCountry(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Variant

    'Should work if you set a reference to the Bloomberge add-in in Tools ~ References.
    PriceHomeCountry = BDP("EUR" & Split(rng2, " ")(1), " Curncy", "PX_Last") * rng1

    'Might work without setting a reference.
    'PriceHomeCountry = Application.Run("BDP", "EUR" & Split(rng2, " ")(1), " Curncy", "PX_Last") * rng1

End Function
```

**Edit:**  Also thanks to @assylias for the heads up on the formula construction.